# Puppeteer For Loop Stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer script that loops through an array of URL's that are navigated to and then scraped form some text. However, with my current setup, the loop stops after the first iteration.

My belief is that it has to do with the for loop setup and the async nature of the function, but after playing around with await at different points in the function, I wasn't able to fix the issue.

Is there a glaring issue with my setup that is stopping the loop early?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    console.log("Step 1 - Call Function")
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    

    const results = [
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/',
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=2',
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=3',
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=4',
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=5',
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=6',
    'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=7'
    ]

    console.log("Step 2 - Loop and Check")
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        console.log(`Step 3 - Loop ${i}`)
        
        page.on('console', async (msg) => {
            const msgArgs = msg.args();
            for (let i = 0; i < msgArgs.length; ++i) {
                console.log(await msgArgs[i].jsonValue());
            }
        });

        await page.goto(results[i]);
        
        const grabText = await page.evaluate(async () => {
            console.log("Step 4 - Grab Text")
            var textArr;
            const contentArea = document.querySelector(".titleline");
            textArr = await Array.from(contentArea.querySelectorAll("a"), e => e.innerText);
            console.log(textArr);
            return textArr;
        });
        // console.log(grabText);
        return grabText;
    }
    console.log("Step 5 - Grab Text")
    console.log(grabText);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: The last line in your for loop `return grabText;` will break control stop the loop and exit the function. If you want o return the text of all pages, maybe put them in an array inside the loop and do the return at the very end

Answer (score 0):

Add a let in your for loop to scope it for each block.

[image]